# Running coroutines function with withContext vs suspendCoroutine

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I wish if you can elaborate about the difference when calling those 3 functions:

```
   lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var res = addTwoNumbers1(2,3)
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var res = addTwoNumbers1(2, 3)
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        var res = addTwoNumbers2(2,3)
    }
```

Functions:

```
suspend fun addTwoNumbers1(num1: Int, num2: Int): Int = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    val res = num1+num2
    cont.resume(res)
}

suspend fun addTwoNumbers2(num1: Int, num2: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val res = num1+num2
    return@withContext res

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First version launches a coroutine using `Dispatcher.IO`, meaning any code inside will execute on background thread, unless you change it

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var res = addTwoNumbers1(2,3)      // This call executes on background thread (IO pool)
}
```

Second version launches a coroutine using `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` (UI thread, this is implicit for `lifecycleScope`)

```
lifecycleScope.launch {                // Starts on UI thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {      // Here thread is changed to background (IO pool)
        var res = addTwoNumbers1(2, 3)
    }
}
```

Third one starts a new coroutine on `UI` thread and then calls a suspending function(doesn't actually suspend) which changes the `Dispatcher` to IO

```
lifecycleScope.launch {              // Starts on UI thread
    var res = addTwoNumbers2(2,3)    // This function changes the dispatcher to IO
}
```

as for your suspending functions, `addTwoNumbers1` is the only one that have the capability to suspend because it calls suspendCoroutine.

`addTwoNumbers2` is not really a suspending function

Comment: So when calling addTwoNumbers2 although it defined as "suspend" it's not really suspending. The thread which calling it does not wait for result?

Comment: exactly, a true suspending function is one that ultimatly calls `suspendCoroutine` or 
`suspendCancellableCoroutine`. otherwise there is no use adding suspend modifier, because no suspension happens in that case.

Comment: The problem is that imposible to remove suspend modifier on the function. There is an error "Suspend function 'withContext' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Comment: You should remove `withContext` from `addTwoNumbers2` and instead use it inside coroutine as you did with second example

Comment: So what benefit using  withContext? Just for forcing other developers who use this function to call it on specified thread (IO for example)?

Comment: If you want `addTwoNumbers2` to be executed in sync then leave the withContext part, because then 'addTwoNumbers2' will block the calling coroutine until its complete. on the other hand if code written in `addTwoNumbers2` can be executed async then use `async` or `launch` in place of `withContext`

Comment: Sorry if I don't fully understand... So if addTwoNumbers2 withContext will block the calling coroutine until its complete and also suspendCoroutine will block calling coroutine until cont.resume called what is the difference?

Comment: suspendCoroutine doesn't block, it suspends the coroutine and cont.resume will resume the coroutine at some later time